# SSL error when connecting to remote SQL server using Java (netbeans)

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, netbeans, sql-server-2005

i asked this question before but got no answers, i think mainly because it was a mess, i'll state the facts and put some quotes from the code under

- im using VMWare, and have one Windows Server 2003 with SQL Server 2005 on it, with a SQL Login, and it has a DNS Service running
- i also have a windows 7 machine running NetBeans8.2 with JDK 8.1, using JDBC 4.2
- i can connect to the server using SQL Manager from the Windows 7 machine
- i can't connect using the java code because of an SSL Error, i am not sure what is causing it
- this is for a school project so i must use SQL server 2005

here's my connection code :

```
    package connectbd;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    
    public class ConnectBD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String jdbcurl;
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        jdbcurl = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQLSERVER;instanceName=SQLE;user=****;password=****;database=DBGR15";
        
        try {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcurl);
            System.out.println("Connection success");
        } catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

This is the error that i get :

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to the SQL Server using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "The SQL Server server returned no response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId ».
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2826)
    ****at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1829)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2391)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2042)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1889)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1120)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:700)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at connectbd.ConnectBD.main(ConnectBD.java:35)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 
The SQL Server server returned no response. The connection was closed. ClientConnectionId
    ****at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:786)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:836)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:829)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:999)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:989)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1756)
    ... 8 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

i believe the causes are somewhere in these 2 lines: the ones marked by **** at the start

i have to deliver a webservices project for school in 2 weeks, and this is kind of a huge obstacle, any quick help or suggestion would be very appreciated

Comment: [1] From your post I'm not sure whether you are asking why the SSL connection isn't working, or why your connection is using SSL. Can you clarify? [2] You stated you _"can connect to the server using SQL Manager from the Windows 7 machine"_, but can you confirm that you can do that _at the same time_ that your project fails to connect? I'm only asking because the error you are getting could simply be because SQL Server wasn't running. [3] Is your SQL Server using a self-signed certificate? [4] What is the name of the JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: That's good news, but your post stated  _"i must use SQL server 2005"_?!

Answer (score 4):

You will need to add few parameters to specify the ssl connection, such as `integratedSecurity=true`, `encrypt=true` and `trustServerCertificate=true`.

```
jdbcurl = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQLSERVER;instanceName=SQLE;user=****;password=****;database=LP_SIBD_GR15;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
```